# How can I upgrade from Eclipse Java SE version to Eclipse for Java EE via Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I downloaded Eclipse plain Java version and now I realize that I need of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers distribution.
I'm new in Eclipse world and I would to know if it is possible (and how) to install Java EE plugins via Eclipse.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a thread in ServerFault that shows how to install the Java EE pluggins for Eclipse [Java EE plugin for Eclipse IDE](https://serverfault.com/questions/98921/java-ee-plugin-for-eclipse-ide)

Additionally you can:

- Help -> Install new software.
- Pick the Mars (or the version you have downloaded such as Luna, Kepler, etc)  repository
- At the bottom there are install options Java EE Development

Comment: On the Eclipse Downloads page there is a (subtle) link to **Compare and Combine Packages** which give instructions https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=mars

Answer (score 2):

To get all of the features of the Java EE edition of Eclipse, there are several packages that need to be installed.  [This page](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr) lists all of the packages that are included in the current Java EE version of Eclipse.  If you want all of the features of the Eclipse for Java EE developers, go to Help --> Install New Software..., select the update site for your version (e.g. Kepler) from the dropdown menu, and select the checkbox for each item listed on the above page that is not already installed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find the 'getting started guides' here helpful.

You probably will need to download the plug-in. The easiest way to do this would be to:

go to Help -> Install new software.
Pick the Galileo(Change accordingly) repository
All the way at the bottom there are install options for **'Web, XML, and JaveEE Development**
... also this is better suited for SO

Answer (score 0):

follow this

**Eclipse 3.3 or earlier, it is NOT possible to upgrade the Eclipse platform itself, only its features. So, you could for example upgrade the CVS feature or the PDE feature from 3.2.0 to 3.2.1, but not eclipse.exe itself.**

and

**Upgrading other features (like CDT, PDT, WTP...) can be done without the need to download a new platform binary, but because many projects align very closely (eg., the Eclipse 3.2 / Callisto or Eclipse 3.3 / Europa release trains) you will likely need to upgrade the Eclipse platform as well.**