# Eclipse 3.8: where is the download site?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I'm a bit confused about Eclipse release 3.8

It seems a bit like a ghost to me: no codename, no download site?

Where are all the packages, like "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers"?

Comment: 3.8? Eclipse.org lists 3.7 (Indigo) and 4.2 (Juno). Alphabet-wise, there is nothing between Indigo and Juno, either.

Comment: Juno included both 4.2 and 3.8 (confusing, but true) - http://www.eclipse.org/projects/releases/releases.php?release=juno

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Eclipse 3.8 and 4.2 were released concurrently as part of the Juno release, but the compilations for various developer types are only available based on version 4.2.

To use Eclipse 3.8, you will need to download the basic platform and install the plugins you need from Eclipse Marketplace or the Juno repository.

Surf to here and download the one labeled Eclipse SDK:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/

Juno repository:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

Comment: So, eclipse 3.8 is based on Juno... but still 100% compatible with 3.7.2?

Comment: Compatible in what sense? Projects are expected to be fully compatible when upgrading to either 3.8 or 4.2. A plugin written for 3.7 should work in either 3.8 or 4.2 as long as it only uses public API. If a plugin references internal code, then compatibility with 3.8 is more likely than compatibility with 4.2, but neither is guaranteed. Note that a compatible plugin may still fail to install if it specifies version dependencies that exclude the target version.

Comment: I've tested Juno release some time ago, and it was far, far from compatible. Even now, the 4.2 release is not compatible. With few adjustments maybe...

Comment: I'm still wondering how to install the EPPs once I install the 3.8 base. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381044/how-do-i-install-an-eclipse-epp-for-example-epp-modeling-feature-on-3-8.

Comment: Anyone struggling with the lack 3.8 packages, should voice their concerns on this petition: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389175

Comment: Update: 3.8.1 is at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.1-201209141540/ - but see @Thomas W's answer to get the latest 3.x version

Comment: Update: moved to http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/
Follow the 3.8.2 link and get the Eclipse SDK for your OS.

Answer (score 18):

**Official 'Eclipse Project 3.x' Stream Downloads page**

```
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.html
```

This has links to 3.8.1 release, and the 3.8 maintenance build.. If you want to link anywhere to 3.8, this is probably the best place.

Note that 3.8 is not a full 'packaged' release -- it's just the core. Features & plugins can be added from within the IDE, to replicate functionality of the Java EE/ PHP/ C++ etc packaged distributions.

3.8 is of particular interest to those (like myself) who are *downgrading from 4.2 Juno* due to the serious performance problems in that release. These seem to affect XML editors, PHP, switching, opening & closing editors -- turning the instant performance of previous Eclipse versions into endless 3-5 second waits.

Indigo 3.7 is the last 'packaged' release available. 3.8 may offer advantages in fixing several Indigo bugs & having Java 7 support.

Comment: I'm not even considering 4.2 without making the code totally native to Juno standards. Compatibility layers, no thanks. BTW, i tested my code with 4.2 and even with the compatibility layer and some workarounds, there were some major problems. Staying with 3.7.

Comment: Also 3.7.1 added Java 7 support.

Answer (score 10):

A link to the recently released **3.8.2**: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. I think I've found a more permanent one, though; see my answer.

Comment: Installed it today, after many hours lost with 3.8.0: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/

Answer (score 3):

None of the links in other answers seem to work anymore, <s>but [The Eclipse Project Updates Sites](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites) page at eclipse.org says it's  http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8 and that works for me</s> and 3.8 has now been moved to the archives. I don't think updates are available anymore.

Comment: That link now gives 404 not found

Comment: Thanks. It seems 3.8 has been moved to the archives now, so perhaps it really is time to update.

Answer (score 0):

To install Java EE into the 3.8.1 download, this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5028910/503025
Java EE is in the Juno upgrade site.