# How do I install an Eclipse EPP (for example EPP Modeling Feature on 3.8)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-juno, eclipse-emf-ecore

How do I install an Eclipse EPP through the software installer for 3.8? I would like to choose the "EPP Modeling Feature" and install all of its packages rather than selecting them all individually.

As an example if I install Eclipse Juno "Eclipse Modeling Tools" and then look at the installed software packages I will see "EPP Modeling Feature 1.5.0.20120620-0855 org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.feature.group.

If I then also install the base Eclipse 3.8 and choose "install new software" and turn off "group by category" I can find the EPPs. I can't install them however since they are written to depend on 4.2 (even though all of their packages run fine on 3.8 also by design).

FYI, [Eclipse 3.8: where is the download site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322349/eclipse-3-8-where-is-the-download-site) gives some background on Juno vs. 3.8, but doesn't specifically answer the question of how to get the EPPs once you have installed the 3.8 base.

Answer (score 0):

Take 4.2. It emulates 3.8 inside itself. And all plugins can be installed by General Purpose Tools->MarketPlace Client from juno updates site.

Comment: Maybe try to install through MarketPlace?