# Eclipse 3.8 update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno, update-site

Where I can find release update site for eclipse 3.8?
I need something like this but for 3.8:

Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

Also I have found next comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322349/eclipse-3-8-where-is-the-download-site)

> Juno included both 4.2 and 3.8 (confusing, but true) - eclipse.org/projects/releases/releases.php?release=juno – studgeek Sep 12 '12 at 4:07

But Juno update site does not contain 3.8 platform (for example there is no org.eclipse.platform.feature.group with version 3.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322349/eclipse-3-8-where-is-the-download-site). 3.8 is not included in Juno repository, you have to download a 3.8 zip package then install other software in it.