# After upgrading to Eclipse Juno facing performance issues

Tags: eclipse

After I have upgraded to Eclipse Juno

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722
```

I am facing following issues:

1. It takes ~5 mins to open eclipse.
2. If I try to clean a project it takes ~10 mins.

The following are the args that I have set

```
-vmargs -Xms256m -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

I have an 8GB RAM installed and I am using Windows 7.

Is there anything I can do about this issue? As during this period my system is stuck.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I went back to 3.8 to get around the performance problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5028910/503025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272).  They have recently released a [minor update (4.2.1)](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1) but much of the main issues with performance have yet to be addressed.  If you read through that ticket you will see that there are a couple of things that can help speed things up immediately.

1. Switch to classic theme. *Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Theme* switch to classic
2. On the same preference page disable animations.

I would add your name to the CC list and you can keep apprised of the improvements to performance.  It seems that many of the performance issues (especially with the XML editor) will not be fixed until 4.2.2.