# Does eclipse have a jsp viewing mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to configure Eclipse (Juno) for opening .jsp files so that it recognizes the jsp syntax and applies language specific formatting?

Comment: If you're working with Eclipse for Java EE developers, then it should. What's your specific question?

Comment: Like is there an editor for jsp files like there is for xml's. Is there a way I can configure eclipse so that I can right click and select to open a jsp with a jsp editor within eclipse is what I'm asking I guess

Comment: Again, this is available in Eclipse for Java Ee developers. Are you using that Eclipse edition?

Comment: No, not at the moment. Can I integrate that edition with my current version of eclipse or will it replace my current version entirely? I'm working on a google-app engine application with the likewise named plugin for Juno, which I'm not sure is available for Java EE.

Comment: Neither am I. Can you provide more info like the details (name, version, plugins) of the tool you're using?

Comment: Sure, I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno), with the Google App Engine plugin for 4.2 (found at https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upgrade from Eclipse Java SE version to Eclipse for Java EE via Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028659/how-can-i-upgrade-from-eclipse-java-se-version-to-eclipse-for-java-ee-via-eclips)

Comment: Oh there we go, that fits the bill perfectly, followed the instructions there for installing the Java EE plugin and now there's a jsp editor! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use the jsp editor from the eclipse java web development tools package. I have kepler, but I'm sure you'll find something similar in juno. Go to *help:install new software* and select a *work with* site (I chose Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler). Then scroll down to find *web, xml, javaee, osgi* and you'll find the *eclipse java web development tools* there.

The jsp editor is ok but it does have some quirks. The right click to select the editor works only within eclipse. This is not the javaee package.

(edit) -- oops --

Should've expanded the comments before I posted. You already got your answer.