# Eclipse Standard Kepler Service Release 2 isn't updated to Eclipse with JavaEE support correct

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-kepler

I install Eclipse Standard Kepler Service Release 2. And now I decide to update it to support Java EE: using Install Updates->Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler->Web, XML, Java EE....

Now I get a lot of features but I can't create Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028659/how-can-i-upgrade-from-eclipse-java-se-version-to-eclipse-for-java-ee-via-eclips)'s an older post, but it refers to the same problem.

Comment: @Geziefer As I wrote above I did it and it doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

this happens in the latest version of eclipse, you need to install "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools"

for this go to Help-> Install New Software ... and select the  ["helios" repository](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/). Then expand "Web, XML, Java EE .." and check the box for "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools". Click "Finish", accept, install and restart.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you missed something, but I just tested that the following works:

- install standard kepler SR2
- go to Help/Install new software
- select Kepler site and expand "Web, XL, Java EE..."
- select "Eclipse Java EE Developer tools" and install
- select New/Project/Web/Dynamic Web Project